# Solvability theorems

Tags: lie-algebras

> Let $L$ be a Lie algebra.
>
> (a) If $L$ is solvable, then so are all subalgebras and homomorphic images of $L$.
>
> (b) If $I$ is a solvable ideal of $L$ such that $L/I$ is solvable, then $L$ itself is solvable.
>
> Proof of (b): Say $(L/I)^{(n)}=0$. Applying part (a) to the canonical homomorphism $\pi:L\rightarrow L/I$, we get $\pi(L^{(n)})=0$, or $L^{(n)}\subset I=\operatorname{Ker}\pi$.

How does $(L/I)^{(n)}=0$ imply $\pi(L^{(n)})=0$? I don't see why this follows from part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$\pi(L^{(n)}) \subseteq (L/I)^{(n)}.$$

This statement is pretty easy to prove by induction, and a good exercise, so I leave it to you.

Comment: Thank you, Jim. Actually, using the base case $\pi(L)=L/I$, don't we have equality $\pi(L^{(n)})\subseteq(L/I)^{(n)}$?

Comment: Probably, but I didn't want to think through whether $I \nsubseteq L^{(n)}$ was an issue or not.